# View CSS Layout Query

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

I have a section of data that loads a main view with a stylesheet etc.  What I am trying to do is just load the stylesheet for my respective function 'addSale' - I just want my form style.

My admintemplate is a full document that implements the required php sections.  Would my best option be to create three files header navigation and footer?  Should I create a separate file for the meta data?

```
    // Main Page Data 
    $data['sales_pages'] = $this->sales_model->getSalesPages();
    $data['cms_pages'] = $this->navigation_model->getCMSPages();
    $data['title'] = 'Sales';
    $data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/sales', $data, TRUE); 
    $this->load->view('admintemplate', $data);
}

function addSale(){
    $data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/testview',$data);
}
```

Comment: You have 3 very vague questions rolled up into one with a strange title. Perhaps try using a [template library](http://www.google.com/search?q=codeigniter+template+library).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/194843/ is pretty simple (although it needs a little work to maximize performance).

Answer (score 0):

Of course it depends on each project but I actually usually do 6 view sections: Open, Header, Nav, Body, Footer, Close:

```
$this->load->view('open', $data);
$this->load->view('header', $data);
$this->load->view('nav', $data);
$this->load->view('body', $data);
$this->load->view('footer', $data);
$this->load->view('close', $data);
```

- The *open* contains meta data, html tag open, javascript includes, and css includes.
- The *header* contains the header to my site.
- The *body* is obviously the body
- The *footer* is the footer
- The *close* is any analytics and closing body, head etc.

As separated as possible without becoming convoluted or duplicating code is recommended.

**Edit:** @Wesley is most right, though, you should use a template library.